# sharepoint search problem

Tags: sharepoint, search

I'm working on a sharepoint project.
After I adding the search web part. The search function behaves weird.

I have crawled the content source and configured the permission.

The following search bar, no matter what I search, I got nothing

[image]

But the advanced search web part can work properly.

[image]

The thing is, in the result page of the advanced search web part, if I choose to see the result of my sharepoint website instead of "Any Site", I got nothing. I am sure that the result of "Any Site" is from my sharepoint site.

[image]

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Regards,

Bin

Comment: Try asking on http://serverfault.com/ or http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question is very similar to your previous one and it appears you have already asked this on Sharepointoverflow, it would be good if you can delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your search log to make sure content is being crawled correctly. It looks like you do not have any results for your a particular site. modify your search webpart to show the scopes drop down an experiment to find out which scopes are not responding correctly and debug from there.

You need to ask this question on serverfault.com or sharepoint.stackexchange.com as this site trys to deal with programming specific errors only.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be crawling a non default zone.  Maybe you're crawling an intranet or extranet zone.  Make sure you crawl the default zone and that the default zone has NTLM authentication enabled and that the crawler has access to the web application via full read policy.

If this is SharePoint 2010 Foundation and you have named your documents_with_underscores, the underscores are not word breakers and as a result no matter what you search for "Documents" "with" or "underscores", in that case, would be successful.  The word "with" would be removed by the content processor (search query and site settings service) in 2010 and the other two words would not be read as separate words because 2010 foundation would treat documents_with_underscores as one word. If you searched for "documents_with_underscores" you would find it.